# Putting attributes with active or selected images

Tags: css

Each product has multiple variants, which are linked to different thumbnails.
I can click to each thumbnails to preview it on a bigger size

I would like the border of the active thumbnail to be more visible.

[image]

I have tried these codes with **:active** and **::selection** but it doesn't work .

```
.productThumbs li img::selection {
    border-color: #ee0a3a !important;
}

.productThumbs li img:active {
    border-color: #ee0a3a !important;
}
```

I have little experience with :active or ::selection attribute

Link of a product page: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/africain/products/boucles-oreilles-fleur-etoilee?variant=6090700914718

Comment: Please add the code of the `ul` instead of linking to a site

Comment: `:active` does not mean what you think it means. You need Javascript.

Comment: Huangism how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong CSS selector. Also, `:active` has an entirely different meaning in this context. It means a link that's currently being activated by the user (think of a link currently being moused down on): Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

The selector you want is this either:

```
.productThumbs li .active
```

or

```
.productThumbs li .active img
```

This would make your statement look like this:

```
.productThumbs li .active img {
    border: 1px solid #ee0a3a;
}
```

Or instead of using `border: 1px solid #ee0a3a;` you can use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ee0a3a;` if you want an easy way to have a larger border without the photo size shrinking.